# I Tried to Update the Kernel?

Tags: kernel

I tried to update my Ubuntu 20.04 kernel but seemed to have found myself with these latest errors. What's the solution?

```
frederick@frederickpina:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
[sudo] password for frederick: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-33-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-33-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/38.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 189 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 265633 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-33-generic_5.4.0-33.37_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-33-generic (5.4.0-33.37) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-33-generic_5.4.0-33.37_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/lib/modules/5.4.0-33-generic/kernel/drivers/media/usb/gspca/gspca_conex.ko.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted

Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-33-generic_5.4.0-33.37_amd64.deb

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
frederick@frederickpina:~$
```

Comment: Check all directories along the path `/lib/modules/5.4.0-33-generic/kernel/drivers/media/usb/gspca/`. They should all be owned by `root:root` and writable by root only.

Comment: Worked for me after a reboot, with a subsequent `sudo apt --fix-broken install` as recommended by `apt-get`.

Answer (score 0):

cheked the owner and is root:root i even run the

```
sudo chown -R root:root /lib/modules/5.4.0-33-generic/*
```

but the error remains... is not always on the same file, for example i have error on:

```
dpkg: error al procesar el archivo /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-extra-5
.4.0-33-generic_5.4.0-33.37_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 no se puede abrir `/lib/modules/5.4.0-33-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/ql
ogic/qlcnic/qlcnic.ko.dpkg-new': Operación no permitida
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-33-generic_5.4.0-33.37_amd64.
deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```